# Django==2.0.7 django/forms/fields.py has some issue when you handle imagefield in your code

Tags: django, django-forms

I faced a problem while handling one ImageField in my model and deployed to production. The model I am using through Django Admin to store data into this model but when I press save data, my application generate "Server Error 500" but when I do not select image file to save there is no error and DEBUG detail trace back tells this.

```
File "/home/asifkhan69/webapps/rmsapp/lib/python3.6/Django-2.0.7-py3.6.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in to_python 611.         
  from PIL import Image

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /admin/vv/institutes/add/
Exception Value: No module named 'PIL'
Request information:
USER: asifkhan
```

The same application is not giving this error on development setup.

I am looking expert answer on this to fix.

Comment: sounds like you don't have pillow installed on your prod server.  what happens when you ssh in, open up a python shell and type `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: yes i checked and pillow was install in different python version env and now installed in correct python env and it is working. thanks